# dataframe column value calculation and replacement

Tags: python, pandas, replace, dataframe, calculated-columns

Need your help in calculating a new value for a DF column and THEN replacing the old value with a calculated value. I am new and having issues pasting the code (my apologies):

In [36]:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'beerstyle': ['light', 'dark','light', 'dark'], 'beername': ['coors', 'guiness','bud', 'guiness'],'flavor': [5,3,3,1], 'taste': [4,5,2,3]})
df
```

Out[36]:

```
beername    beerstyle   flavor  taste
0   coors     light         5    4
1   guiness   dark          3    5
2   bud       light         3    2
3   guiness   dark          1    3

brStmean = df.loc[(df["beerstyle"]=='light')].flavor.mean()

brStmean1 = df.loc[(df["beerstyle"]=='dark')].flavor.mean()

brNamean = df.loc[(df["beername"]=='guiness')].flavor.mean()
df.loc[(df["beerstyle"]=='dark')].flavor - brStmean1
```

This works fine. The values are calculated

However, when I try:

```
df=df.loc[(df["beerstyle"]=='dark')].flavor - brStmean1
df

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-5f276edddc66> in <module>()
----> 1 df=df.loc[(df["beerstyle"]=='dark')].flavor - brStmean1
2 df

C:\Users\Toly\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
519     def __getitem__(self, key):
520         try:
--> 521             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
522 
523             if not np.isscalar(result):


1593 
1594         try:
 -> 1595             return self._engine.get_value(s, k)
1596         except KeyError as e1:
1597             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer','boolean']:

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:3113)()

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:2844)()

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3761)()

KeyError: 'beerstyle'
```

Does this mean that I can not replace the column with a calculated value? Then how can I create a new DF where the only difference is a calculated column?

Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH both of you! This was a huge issue for me and I was out of options completely!

Answer (score 1):

Let's answer both your questions.

1) Does this mean that I can not replace the column with a calculated volume?

You can replace a column with a calculated volume. Try referencing the column you are trying to replace with new values as:

`df["column"] = new_values`

Note that new_values should be a list.

2) How can I create a new DF where the only difference is a calculated column?

`df_new = df_old
df_new["new_column"] = new_values`

On a side note, your code works fine without any error for me. And assuming that it is correct, it will return a DF as well. Not sure why you are getting a KeyError for "beerstyle." Try running your entire code again in the same environment; it might just work.

Comment: Trust me I tried the whole day. trying different versions, closing and rerunning the script step by step. Nothing worked. Sorry - it is value and not a volume. My bad! This was driving me crazy:)  Just to add: it is difficult to reference with "new values" as you suggest since this a large dataset. Thus it has to be  a loc type referencing column's name or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
df['flavor'] = df['flavor'].mask(df["beerstyle"] == 'dark', df['flavor'] - brStmean1)
```

Although this type of operation is generally cleaner expressed as a [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

```
df['flavor'] = df.groupby('beerstyle')['flavor'].transform(lambda x: x - x.mean())
```

EDIT:

To expand on why your old method didn't work - when you do `df = ...` python is going to assign whatever happens on the right to the name `df`.  Naked assignment like this (not sure exactly what the term is) cannot modify an existing object, in `pandas` or otherwise.

So you need to do something that that says, "this is the part of the DataFrame I want to assign to."  To use your code again, one way to do this would be to index exactly the part of the DataFrame you want to replace on both sides.  E.g.

```
df.loc[(df["beerstyle"]=='dark'), 'flavor'] = df.loc[(df["beerstyle"]=='dark'), 'flavor'] - brStmean1
```

As you can see, this is a bit awkward to write (duplicated condition), `.mask` is just a convenience method that returns the new value where the condition is true, and the old value otherwise, so you can assign directly to `df["flavor"]`

Comment: Wow! It worked! i spent hours trying to get this. I tried to add points to you but still have no rep as I am very new. Could you, please briefly explain why my attempts have failed?

Comment: @Toly see edit, also the [indexing docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/indexing.html)

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense!